# Scrollview Images creates issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am pick Images using Camera in my app & try to show in horizontal scrollview.

**But the images are overlapping**

**My code**

```
-(IBAction)act_photo:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    //picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker via Camera
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [arr_images insertObject:chosenImage atIndex:0];
        [self scrollImages_Setup2];

    }];

}

-(void)scrollImages_Setup2
{    
    for (int k=0; k<arr_images.count; k++) {

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame) * k) + CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), 0, CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scl.frame))];

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image=[arr_images objectAtIndex:k] ;
        [scl addSubview:imageView];
    }

    scl.contentSize = CGSizeMake((CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame) * arr_images.count)+CGRectGetWidth(scl.frame), CGRectGetHeight(scl.frame));

}
```

**Problem**

**Image1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

As shown above first I was taken Landscape Image2 & then I was taken Portrait Image 1 .

but as you see, Image 1 has background of Image2.

I think this is because there is something going wrong with scrollview?

**Possiblity 2(mostly)** Scrollview keeps strong reference of Imageview evenif it is deleted from array

**Let me know how to solve this?**

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks**

Comment: why are you adding images again.when you choose image second time then it will again add image for first one also in scrollview.because you are adding all images everytime you choose a image from camera roll it is getting overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Y value in you loop, your image Y value same any time,

Answer (score 0):

Each time you take a new image, your completion-Handler puts the new image as the first element into your array and then calls `[self scrollImages_Setup2];` where you iterate over all elements in your array and add them as new subviews to your scrollview.

When you take the first image (Image1) it's getting added to the array and then added as and subview to your scrollview. When you take the second image (Image2) it's getting added to the array as the first element. So then there are two elements in the array (Image2 and Image1) which are both getting added as subview to the scrollview. But Image1 has already been added to the scrollview, so that's causing your problem.

A solution to your problem could be either to always add only the new image and calculate the x position with the number of elements in your array, or to always remove all subviews before you add and layout all images again.